# PI4J + Adafruit LCD with MCP23017

Tags: pi-2, java, pi4j, lcd, adafruit

[Got this device](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1115).

[image]

[image]

[Python example char_lcd_plate.py](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/blob/master/examples/char_lcd_plate.py) is working perfect.

But I would like to manage it with Pi4J.

I copied bits from [python example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/blob/master/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py)

```
LCD_PLATE_RS            = 15
LCD_PLATE_RW            = 14
LCD_PLATE_EN            = 13
LCD_PLATE_D4            = 12
LCD_PLATE_D5            = 11
LCD_PLATE_D6            = 10
LCD_PLATE_D7            = 9
```

Java:

```
LCD lcd = new I2CLcdDisplay(2, 16, 1, 0x20, 0, 15, 14, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12);
lcd.clear();
lcd.write(0, "111 ");
lcd.write(1, "222");
```

Init is fine but I have blue boxes on the screen and no any updates.
Any advice?

**Update 1**

```
import com.pi4j.component.lcd.LCD;
import com.pi4j.component.lcd.impl.I2CLcdDisplay;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Display {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        LCD lcd = new I2CLcdDisplay(2, 16, 1, 0x20, 0, 15, 14, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.write(0, "111 ");
        lcd.write(1, "222");
    }

}
```

**Links:**

[How to get pin addresses on a MCP23017](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/how-to-get-pin-addresses-on-a-mcp23017)

Comment: I would say you need to adjust the contrast

Comment: @Dirk I checked contrast. It is fine for python example.

Comment: can you show your complete code? i think its more a logical problem rather than a programin one, you might be printing the characters fine the first time, but you need a loop to make the refresh, i used to have that problem long a go using another pic

Comment: @lightshadown see "update 1"